# Divider item does not allow my code to run

Tags: android, navigation

Within my navigation drawer, I am trying to execute a code to start a new activity so it moves from one activity to another. However, When I use a `DividerDrawerItem()` it does not execute the last case statement (4). I've tried it without the `DividerDrawerItem()` and it works but when I add it in, it does not.

```
PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1).withName("Home Page");
PrimaryDrawerItem item2 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2).withName("Rank Table");
PrimaryDrawerItem item3 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(3).withName("Report");
PrimaryDrawerItem item4 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(4).withName("Log out");

//create the drawer and remember the `Drawer` result object
 Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
     .withActivity(this)
     .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
     .withToolbar(toolbar)
     .addDrawerItems(
      item1, item2,item3,
      new DividerDrawerItem(),
      item4

              )
        .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        // do something with the clicked item :D
                        switch(position){
                            case 1: startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, HomePage.class));
                                break;
                            case 2: startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, RankT.class));
                                break;
                            case 3: startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this,Report.class));
                            break;
                            case 4: firebaseAuth.signOut();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this,MainActivity.class));
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is using *position* where it should use *identifier*.

Change `switch(position)` to `switch((int) drawerItem.getIdentifier())`

Comment: There is no statement called switch(drawerItem.identifier) , its getIdentifier and withIdentifier.

Comment: @AceB I've updated my answer. I am not familiar with this drawer library. Let me know if it works for you now.

Comment: The getIdentifier() method requires the method to be an int. switch((int) drawerItem.getIdentifier()) is the right answer. Thank you.